# sync data from Cordova from IndexedDB and webSQL

Tags: android, ios, windows, cordova, pouchdb

I’m building an mobile application in Cordova. And need to save user data.

When a user has no internet connection, the data will be locally saved. When connected to the internet it should sync with an online database.
Devices: Windows Phone, Android, iOS.

I’ve read about CouchDB and PouchDB. Now I have trouble understanding the following:
iOS will only work with WebSQL, Windows only with IndexedDB and Android with both.
How can I sync the WebSQL and IndexedDB so data inserted from an windows phone can be shown on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about the underlying databases. You will always work with JSON documents (like described in the [docs](https://pouchdb.com/guides/documents.html#whats-a%E2%80%93document)) in a PouchDB or CouchDB. You will store a JSON document on any operating system, synchronize to another operating system and get a JSON document from the synced database there.

What might be causing your trouble understanding is how PouchDB saves those JSON documents internally. PouchDB is not a database itself, it uses other databases to store it's data ([taken from the docs](https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html)). Depending on the browser you're running in, IndexedDB, WebSQL or both are available. See the Mobile chart [here](https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html#pouchdb_in_the_browser). Safari does only support WebSQL, Internet Explorer Mobile only IndexedDB, Chrome both. If you care, check out the caniuse for [IndexedDB](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb) and [WebSQL](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage) aswell.

If it's a requirment to use the same underlying database on every operating system you might want to use a SQLite database with the corresponding adapter as Dave mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) plugin, you have a native SQLite DB with unlimited storage (unlike WebSQL/IndexedDB in the WebView) and a common WebSQL-like interface which will work on all of your target platforms.

You can then use the [PouchDB adapter](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite) to provide the PouchDB interface.